# Why is Caliburn Micro closing all of my screens when initial login is closed?

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro

I have a login form: LoginView.xaml and LoginViewModel.cs which inherits from Window. When the login is successful, I am closing the form using TryClose().

My AppBoostrapper.cs class does the following:

```
var shell = IoC.Get<IShell>();
windowManager.ShowDialog(shell);
```

(I have also tried using DisplayRootViewFor() instead but the app just starts and exits - apparently not entering into the form event loop).

My ShellViewModel looks like this:

```
public class ShellViewModel : Conductor<IScreen>.Collection.OneActive, IShell 
    public ShellViewModel()
    {
        var login = IoC.Get<Login.LoginViewModel>();
        login.UserName = login.App.Get(RegKeyName.LastUser);
        login.AppVersion = login.App.AppVersion;
        var windowManager = IoC.Get<IWindowManager>();
        windowManager.ShowDialog(login);
            
        //ActivateItem(login);
    }
}
```

So when the shell starts, it displays the login screen. However, as soon as the login screen closes, the shell closes as well. I can kind of work around this by making my login screen a UserControl and calling ActivateItem instead (and then when the UserControl closes the shell stays running), but I really want the login to be a true Window and not contained within the initial shell.

How can I keep my Shell running event after the Login screen has closed?

**EDIT: Here's what I changed to get it to work**

In my Login screen I was using TryClose(). In reality, it made more sense to hide the screen so AppBootstrapper could determine if the login was successful or not via a property my LoginViewModel (and continue or exit the app). So I changed TryClose() to Hide instead:

```
 (GetView() as Window).Hide();
```

Then I moved the code that was previously in the ShellViewModel constructor back into AppBootstrapper. So now my OnStartup looks like this:

```
_windowManager = IoC.Get<IWindowManager>();
if (Login(_windowManager))
{
    StartApp(_windowManager);
}

Application.Shutdown();
```

And my Login method in AppBootstrapper looks like this:

```
protected bool Login(IWindowManager windowManager)
{
    var login = IoC.Get<Login.LoginViewModel>();
    windowManager.ShowDialog(login);
    return login.IsAuthenticated;
}
```

It seems like I should probably release the login form from the windowManager at some point, but in my case having it available actually makes some sense as we allow the users to login again as different users from within the app.

Answer (score 4):

Try changing the [ShutdownMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.shutdownmode.aspx) of your application.

- OnLastWindowClose - Shutdown when all Window objects are closed
- OnMainWindowClose - Shutdown when `App.Current.MainWindow` closes
- OnExplicitShutdown - Shutdown only when application is told to shutdown

The default is `OnLastWindowClose`, so if you close your last window before opening a new one, the application will shut down.

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        this.ShutdownMode = System.Windows.ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the owner of your login window to null.

```
dynamic settings = new ExpandoObject();
settings.Owner = null;
```

and then :

```
windowManager.ShowDialog(login, null, settings);
```

Comment: Good thought but that doesn't work either, even after adjusting your settings example (which won't compile). I tried:

dynamic settings = new ExpandoObject();
settings.Owner = null: